# IDLE and Teminal unable to import an installed module

Tags: python-3.x, macos, python-2.7

I've been trying to import discord.py into my code for quite some time now and it hasn't been working even though it is definitely installed, none of the fixing methods from other similar questions worked either.

Terminal and IDLE unable to import discord.py

```
Python 3.8.3 (v3.8.3:6f8c8320e9, May 13 2020, 16:29:34) 
[Clang 6.0 (clang-600.0.57)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import discord.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'discord.py'
>>>
```

```
MacBook-Pro:~ pyaesonemyo$ python
Python 2.7.10 (default, Feb  7 2017, 00:08:15) 
[GCC 4.2.1 Compatible Apple LLVM 8.0.0 (clang-800.0.34)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import discord.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: No module named discord.py
```

Proof that discord.py is installed

```
MacBook-Pro:~ pyaesonemyo$ pip install discord.py
Requirement already satisfied: discord.py in /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages (1.3.3)
Requirement already satisfied: websockets!=7.0,!=8.0,!=8.0.1,<9.0,>=6.0 in /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages (from discord.py) (8.1)
Requirement already satisfied: aiohttp<3.7.0,>=3.6.0 in /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages (from discord.py) (3.6.2)
Requirement already satisfied: multidict<5.0,>=4.5 in /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages (from aiohttp<3.7.0,>=3.6.0->discord.py) (4.7.6)
Requirement already satisfied: attrs>=17.3.0 in /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages (from aiohttp<3.7.0,>=3.6.0->discord.py) (19.3.0)
Requirement already satisfied: yarl<2.0,>=1.0 in /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages (from aiohttp<3.7.0,>=3.6.0->discord.py) (1.4.2)
Requirement already satisfied: chardet<4.0,>=2.0 in /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages (from aiohttp<3.7.0,>=3.6.0->discord.py) (3.0.4)
Requirement already satisfied: async-timeout<4.0,>=3.0 in /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages (from aiohttp<3.7.0,>=3.6.0->discord.py) (3.0.1)
Requirement already satisfied: idna>=2.0 in /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages (from yarl<2.0,>=1.0->aiohttp<3.7.0,>=3.6.0->discord.py) (2.9)
```

```
MacBook-Pro:~ pyaesonemyo$ pip show discord.py
Name: discord.py
Version: 1.3.3
Summary: A Python wrapper for the Discord API
Home-page: https://github.com/Rapptz/discord.py
Author: Rapptz
Author-email: None
License: MIT
Location: /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages
Requires: websockets, aiohttp
Required-by: 
MacBook-Pro:~ pyaesonemyo$
```

My sys.path:

```
MacBook-Pro:~ pyaesonemyo$ python3
Python 3.8.3 (v3.8.3:6f8c8320e9, May 13 2020, 16:29:34) 
[Clang 6.0 (clang-600.0.57)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import sys
>>> sys.path
['', '/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python38.zip', '/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8', '/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/lib-dynload', '/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages']
>>>
```

I've also tried out multiple popular fixes and still failed.

```
MacBook-Pro:~ pyaesonemyo$ sudo chmod -R ugo+rX /lib/python3.8/site-packages/
chmod: /lib/python3.8/site-packages/: No such file or directory
```

```
MacBook-Pro:~ pyaesonemyo$ python3 -m pip install discord.py
Requirement already satisfied: discord.py in /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages (1.3.3)
Requirement already satisfied: aiohttp<3.7.0,>=3.6.0 in /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages (from discord.py) (3.6.2)
Requirement already satisfied: websockets!=7.0,!=8.0,!=8.0.1,<9.0,>=6.0 in /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages (from discord.py) (8.1)
Requirement already satisfied: chardet<4.0,>=2.0 in /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages (from aiohttp<3.7.0,>=3.6.0->discord.py) (3.0.4)
Requirement already satisfied: attrs>=17.3.0 in /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages (from aiohttp<3.7.0,>=3.6.0->discord.py) (19.3.0)
Requirement already satisfied: async-timeout<4.0,>=3.0 in /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages (from aiohttp<3.7.0,>=3.6.0->discord.py) (3.0.1)
Requirement already satisfied: yarl<2.0,>=1.0 in /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages (from aiohttp<3.7.0,>=3.6.0->discord.py) (1.4.2)
Requirement already satisfied: multidict<5.0,>=4.5 in /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages (from aiohttp<3.7.0,>=3.6.0->discord.py) (4.7.6)
Requirement already satisfied: idna>=2.0 in /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages (from yarl<2.0,>=1.0->aiohttp<3.7.0,>=3.6.0->discord.py) (2.9)
```

NOTE: Using `python -m pip install <package>` without python3 gives out this error

```
MacBook-Pro:~ pyaesonemyo$ python -m pip install discord.py
DEPRECATION: Python 2.7 reached the end of its life on January 1st, 2020. Please upgrade your Python as Python 2.7 is no longer maintained. pip 21.0 will drop support for Python 2.7 in January 2021. More details about Python 2 support in pip, can be found at https://pip.pypa.io/en/latest/development/release-process/#python-2-support
Defaulting to user installation because normal site-packages is not writeable
Collecting discord.py
  Using cached discord.py-0.16.12.tar.gz (414 kB)
Collecting aiohttp<1.1.0,>=1.0.0
  Using cached aiohttp-1.0.5.tar.gz (499 kB)
    ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
     command: /usr/bin/python -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'/private/var/folders/tk/mbdd48gd5614t0l0j0xztrdr0000gn/T/pip-install-mbx8EX/aiohttp/setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'/private/var/folders/tk/mbdd48gd5614t0l0j0xztrdr0000gn/T/pip-install-mbx8EX/aiohttp/setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' egg_info --egg-base /private/var/folders/tk/mbdd48gd5614t0l0j0xztrdr0000gn/T/pip-pip-egg-info-3n4ucd
         cwd: /private/var/folders/tk/mbdd48gd5614t0l0j0xztrdr0000gn/T/pip-install-mbx8EX/aiohttp/
    Complete output (5 lines):
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
      File "/private/var/folders/tk/mbdd48gd5614t0l0j0xztrdr0000gn/T/pip-install-mbx8EX/aiohttp/setup.py", line 60, in <module>
        raise RuntimeError("aiohttp requires Python 3.4.2+")
    RuntimeError: aiohttp requires Python 3.4.2+
    ----------------------------------------
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: python setup.py egg_info Check the logs for full command output.
```

Comment: Use `import discord` without the py extension

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I was actually being very dumb by adding the .py extension in the importing code.

remove the .py from

```
import discord.py
```

will fix it as suggested by @jadz

Answer (score -1):

You are installing Discord.py to Python 2.7 but you're trying to use it in Python 3

Comment: Oh have i?, i'm not actually sure of myself but I did python3 -m pip install discord.py (if that's the command that installs discord.py to python3) And, even if i installed discord.py to python2.7, it still doesn't work considering i tried importing discord.py in the built in python for terminal which is 2.7. :(